# What does % value means in CSS gradient?

Tags: css

What does the **percentage (%) value** means in the `background-image` property in CSS? For example in this code:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(140deg, cyan 0%, purple 50%, lime 75%);
```

How does the % affects the color of cyan, purple, and lime above?

Comment: They’re color stops. Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means color stops. `background-image: linear-gradient(140deg, cyan 0%, purple 50%, lime 75%);` means start at cyan at 0% and change to purple at 50% and lime at 75%

It will turn cyan to purple at the 50% mark, and then transitions from purple to lime over 35% of the gradient.

see the difference between not doing % and doing %

```css
#first {
    background-image: linear-gradient(140deg, cyan, purple, lime);
}
#second {
    background-image: linear-gradient(140deg, cyan 0%, purple 50%, lime 75%);
}
```

```html
<div id="first">Hello world</div>
<div id="second">Hello world</div>
```

also see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient